# Running automated Web browser tests under Hudson

Tags: selenium, hudson, automated-tests, watin

I'm running Hudson for my automated builds and love it.

I'd now like to create automated Web browser tests using either WaTiN (preferred) or Selenium.

As my Hudson runs as a Windows service (under Tomcat), how can I configure this to run? Will I be forced to log in as a user on the Hudson box so my automated browser tests will find a browser? Or is there some other sorcery with an interactive session that I can conjure up?

If possible I'd like the Hudson box itself to run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I've found that WaTin won't work so well as I'd need to configure Hudson to run in an interactive Java session.

[Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/), however, is perfect - there's a [Hudson plug-in](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Selenium+Plugin) that can control it, too.

So that's what we'll use.

Comment: Why exactly would Hudson have to run in an interactive session?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd now like to create automated Web
>   browser tests ... my Hudson runs as a
>   Windows service ... Will I be forced
>   to log in as a user on the Hudson box
>   so my automated browser tests will
>   find a browser? Or is there some other
>   sorcery with an interactive session
>   that I can conjure up? If possible I'd
>   like the Hudson box itself to run the
>   tests.

A Windows service can indeed run a browser, even when logged in as the LocalSystem account. We have that exact setup, with Hudson installed as a Windows service, although deploying it to Tomcat and running that as a service should work equally well. We use Sahi for our automated testing, which runs our test suite in both IE and Firefox.

You didn't say what problem you had with Watin, but in case it's relevant, Sahi needs to set the browser's HTTP proxy to a special host and port. This works no problems with Firefox because Sahi configures its proxy via a profile specified on the Firefox command line. IE is a little tricker, because its proxy settings are in the Windows registry, and when running as the LocalSystem account, these come from a special place in the registry (not HKCU as for a logged-in user). See [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/34940/how-do-i-configure-proxy-settings-for-local-system) for the details. If that was the problem you were having, you may yet be able to achieve your goal of running everything on the Hudson box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Selenium+Plugin)? This shows the Selenium Grid plug-in to Hudson.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting; but it was WaTiN I was hoping to automate if possible. (I know WaTiN and like it, word on the grapevine is that Selenium is a little more tricky, but if I need to learn Selenium to do this then so be it.)

Comment: Your answer makes no sense without clicking on the link.   Can you expand?

Comment: @Michael, that's because the link has an answer. Should I copy-paste it?

Comment: No but how about saying what's in the link. Is it a picture of Jon Skeet? What is it?

Comment: I can't imagine why people continue downvoting this answer, since it provides the same link as the accepted answer.